# Two methods to catch exception, which one is preferable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

OK there is function called doProcess(), I want to catch the exception which could happen inside of this function. I am confused because sometime I noticed that there is some difference if we try to catch exception inside of the function or outside.
So please tell me is there any difference and which method is preferable?
I am using VS C++ 2010 in Win 7. Thanks.

**Catching inside of the function..**

```
void doProcess()
{
  try{
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
         Performcalculations();
         .
         .
         .
      }
      performanotherProcess();
      .
      .
  }
  catch(exception e) {
      cout<<e.what()<<endl;
  }
```

}

**Catching outside in the callback function.**

```
void callback()
{
   try{
      doProcess();
   }
   catch(exception e) {
      cout<<e.what()<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: `<<cout` what is this?

Comment: If you can handle the exception in `doProcess` then do so.

Comment: @Ryan Haining, this is human error. ;) my mistake. corrected.

Comment: there's still another one in your second code block

Comment: "I noticed that there is some difference" - difference to what?

Comment: @kfsone, difference means that if try catch inside of the function, it catch the exception but if you put them outside (second example) it does not. this is what I observed.

Comment: In the VS IDE, under "Debug" there is an "Exceptions" entry (Ctrl+Alt+E) where you can ask the VS debugger to trap exceptions when they happen rather than after they are caught, this may help you step thru the problem. You should try to catch the exception by reference so that you are not constructing objects, though, as the object construction could potentially throw an exception of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what level can best handle the exception. As the case may be, you may even want to catch it on the lower level, perform some exception-handling action, then re-throw it and catch it again on the higher level to process it further there.

Exception handling may involve special actions that are not performed if no exception is thrown. Examples include:

- Logging a warning or error message
- Cleaning up resources
- Modifying parameters and re-attempting to run the function that failed
- Adding information to the exception object before re-throwing it

Not each of these actions may be possible for the low-level function. For example, the logger may not be available on the low level, or certain resources that need to be cleaned up may not be accessible from there. In these cases you need to throw (or catch and re-throw) the exception and catch it on a higher level.

It all depends on which level has access to the resources that are required to handle the exception. Catching and re-throwing several times, or catching and re-throwing as a different exception type, are also perfectly possible and sometimes the right thing to do.

---

I should also say that it's generally a good idea to catch the exception by reference, rather than copy:

```
catch (my_exception &e)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Reasons include: a) You save a copy, b) You benefit of type polymorphism (as exceptions are often part of a type-hierarchy of exception types), c) You can, in a natural way, call member functions of the original exception object and/or add information to it on each level it's caught and re-thrown. If you don't add information, but simply catch (and possibly re-throw), catching it as `const`-reference is also possible.

Comment: You usually pass it by *const reference* rather than pure reference.

Comment: @Rapptz Opinions are divided over this, and there are other questions where this was discussed in the comments. I am not going to have an argument about which is better; in any case neither is incorrect or extremely risky.

Answer (score 1):

catch the expection in where you handle, if you want doProcess() has expection handle, then you should put try{} catch(){} in doProcess(), However if you want the doProcess() could report a expection, then just do the throw work. It depend on your code and your design.